# Having trouble reusing a variable for multiple independent functions

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a generic text adventure game to get better in Python but I'm having trouble with reusing a variable.  I'm going to have other functions that will call the character by name and I'm not really sure how to get that to work.  I tried making "name" a global variable but errors.  Here is my code so far:

```
def name_grab():
    name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
    print name

name_grab()

# it begins!

def start_quest(name):
    print name  
    print "You find yourself washed up on a beach."
    print "Your ship was sunk by mercenaries during a violent storm on the ocean."
    print "You are coverred in seaweed and you keep coughing up salty ocean water."
    print "All you seem to have on you is your gun which was ruined by the water."
    print "You need to find a new weapon and find out where you are."

start_quest()
```

Comment: `start_quest(name_grab())`? `name_grab` will need to *return* `name` though.

Answer (score 1):

```
def name_grab():
    name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
    return name

# it begins!

def start_quest(name):
    print name  
    print "You find yourself washed up on a beach."
    print "Your ship was sunk by mercenaries during a violent storm on the ocean."
    print "You are coverred in seaweed and you keep coughing up salty ocean water."
    print "All you seem to have on you is your gun which was ruined by the water."
    print "You need to find a new weapon and find out where you are."

name = name_grab()

start_quest(name)
```

Comment: If I create another function later though I don't want it to ask the characters name again

Comment: Have modified the answer to store the name in `name` global variable.

Comment: @GrillerGrog no problem! :) Please 'tick' the answer as correct, if it solved your issue.

Comment: Hmmm I don't see that option.  I think its because my reputation is new and still low?